# Strip out characters from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string similar to `BR450L` and I am trying to strip out `BR`(from the beginning) and `L` from the end.
Can anyone assist me with doing that in a single pass. I want to use that condition in a `conditional (ternary) operator`  and wrap that outcome with a function.

Comment: Are you trying to get the number in between?
Is the string always going to be in this format: "BR"###"L"?
Some more details, please, so I/we can help.

Comment: If you provide code that you've tried, sample inputs, desired outputs - your question won't be down-voted by

Comment: Yes, am trying to get the number that's between. I will be using `parseInt` eventually to convert the string into an `int`

Comment: James==Utkarsh?!?!?
Two users/Impersonation/SO bug?!?

Comment: `+"BR450L".match(/\d/g).join("")` will get you the number.
`"BR450L".match(/\d/g).join("")` will get you the string with digits.
`"BR450L".match(/\d/g)` will get you an array of digits.
It will collect all digits, so "3XC6UR9" will return 369, and, if using the `+`, "0x0t7y" will return 7 (no zeros).

Comment: `function(parseInt(displayValue.includes("BR") ? displayValue.replace("BR", "") : )));`
I tried something like this but that just works for BR. For stripping out `L`, I will have to do another pass which I don't want.

Comment: Ok, using this way:
`parseInt(displayValue.replace("BR","").replace("L",""))`.
Is it ALWAYS going to be "BR"ddd"L"?

Comment: Why do you want to use ternary?

Comment: thanks @iAmOren . You solution worked. and no, I dont want ternary anymore with your solution. it became very straightforward when I tried your solution

Comment: excellent!  glad to help!
I'll make it into an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Can you show us your use of my solution in your code?
Perhaps as a footer in the question.

Answer (score -1):

If the format of the string is constant then...

```
const stripOutNum = str => Number(str.slice(2, -1))
```

for example:

```
stripOutNum('BR450L') // returns 450
```

If you wanted a function that tests whether the 'inner' number matches another number...

```
const checkNumMatch = (str, num) => {
  return Number(str.slice(2, -1)) === num
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Extract ALL Digits from a Sting:
`string.match(/\d/g)`
Returns an Array.
To cast into String:
`string.match(/\d/g).join("")`
To cast into a Number:
`+string.match(/\d/g).join("")`
or
`parseFloat(string.match(/\d/g).join(""))`

```js
var string = "BR560L";

console.log("string=\"" + string + "\"");
console.log("as String digit Array=[" + string.match(/\d/g) + "]");
console.log("as digit String=\"" + string.match(/\d/g).join("") + "\"");
console.log("as Number using \"+\"=\"" + (+string.match(/\d/g).join("")) +"\"");
console.log("as Number using \"parseFloat\"=" + parseFloat(string.match(/\d/g).join("")));
```